# How to find elemental modulus of NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to get the elemental modulus (each element of the array is modulated by number x and returned in array format) of the following numpy array:

```
    test = numpy.array([
              [5, 2],
              [1, 4]
           ])
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: You can use this in-built function as mentioned here in the docs - "https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.mod.html"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy.mod`, demo:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> test = numpy.array([
              [5, 2],
              [1, 4]
           ])
>>> numpy.mod(test,2)
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 0]], dtype=int32)
>>>
```

Comment: @JamesA Happy to help, :-), 

Comment: @JamesA Don't forget to accept my answer if it works :-)